# Link will not direct to local server resource

Tags: html

After running code I generate a link to redirect me to a directory found on the local server to which I have full access.

When clicking the link after run i get error message in the console : "not allowed to load local resource", but if I copy the same link and put it in a new browser tab, it functions correctly and redirects me to the specified directory. This issue is not specific to browser, the problem appears in all types of browsers.

Example for link using File Protocol :

```
<a href="file:///192.168.***/xxx/aaa/bbb">Link</a>
```

Comment: Is that the actual URL, with missing `:` and all?

Comment: You probably don't need to obfuscate an internal IP address that's only relevant from within your local network.

Comment: if you need to load resource from server, remove `file///`, add `http://`

Comment: Your link is weird btw

Comment: we are in the same network, it's not my machine

Comment: it's not web server, i can't use http protocol

Answer (score 0):

When you put a URL directly in the address bar then you, the user, are explicitly requesting it and (in theory) know what you are doing.

When you click on a link, the browser doesn't trust that the author of the page isn't trying to trick you, so additional security restrictions are applied.

Comment: is there are any way to override it ?